# How to install cudnn and cuda toolkit in a python virtual environment?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, cudnn

I have created a python virtual environment in the current working directory. It has cuda-python installed along with tensorflow and other packages. I have tried to run the
following script to check if tensorflow can access the GPU or not.

`python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"`

The script raises the following error when run -

`could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

According to what I have seen online, the error is due to the cudnn and cudatoolkit modules not being installed. The solution to this is to install them using anaconda as follows.

`conda install -c anaconda cudnn`

The above command seems to be installing the packages where anaconda is installed, but I do not have write permissions to that directory. I do have write permissions for the current working directory in which the virtual environment is set up.

Now, is there a way to install cudnn and cuda toolkit into the virtual environment present in the current working directory?
What I basically want to do is:

`source .environment/bin/activate; pip install cudnn;`

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure you are in a virtual environment, while installing compatible CUDA and cuDNN for GPU support as per this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).

For this, open the Anaconda prompt and type:

```
conda activate <virtual_environment_name>

conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0  # for tensorflow version >2.5
```

and install the tensorflow using:

```
conda install pip
pip install tensorflow-gpu  # pip install tensorflow-gpu==<specify version>
Or
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Finally, verify the GPU setup with the below code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

Please refer to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) link for more information.